# How to fix nav in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, phpbb

CSS Problem with my topNav in IE6

HTML Page:
http://www.faressoft.net

[image]

Comment: My bet is an `inline-block` property that IE6 translates into `block`.

Comment: It looks like you also need a png fix for IE to recognize the transparent rounded corners on your images.

Comment: @Moses you are right, but it is not important now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using inline-block **instead** of float:right, or define widths for your float rights.

```
div#buttons ul { text-align:right; }
div#buttons div.tabLeft { display:inline-block; }
```

for IE6/IE7 feed a different rule in conditional comments and add

```
div#buttons div.tabLeft { display:inline; }
```

The `display:inline` is necessary after inline-block for IE6/IE7. It is a must, since divs are not naturally inline ( bug in the engine ).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a single `<li>` item inside each div class 'tableft-c' I would just use:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then float them right. Your code is more convoluted than it need to be here.

And meder is correct, you must assign widths to anything that you float. IE6 is very unforgiving with messy code, unlike the more modern browsers.